# is there a way to differentiate between whether the keypresses are done by a user or script?

Tags: python, pynput

I am writing a program with "pynput" which uses Listener() to detect key presses and then based on them performs some action. However one of these actions is typing by sending keystrokes with Controller(). The issue is when Controller is typing something, those keystrokes are also detected by Listener. I want the Listener thread to only listen to key presses done by the user and not by the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's impossible, but you could try to ignore input right when the Controller() writes.